# Show hide information on click

Tags: javascript, php, sqlite

Hi I am first year student and I want to create web where the event is displayed and user can display on click additional information, yet I can not get it to work.

```
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT*from Elections");

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    echo htmlentities($row['Event']);
      echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", 20);  

    echo '<div id="hide">';
    <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'none';

    echo htmlentities($row['InfoEvent']);
        echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", 20); 

    echo htmlentities($row['Month']);

        echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", 20); 

    echo htmlentities($row['Postcode']);
        echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", 20); 

    echo '<br>';
```

echo '';
And I get error when the  shows that is unexpected '<'

Comment: Your `<script>` should be echoed as well

Comment: _“And I get error when the shows that is unexpected '<'”_ - of course you do, because you just put an HTML element directly into the PHP code ... You need to go learn the syntax basics. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: Write your code with PHP in HTML instead of HTML in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'none';
```

With

```
echo ('<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "none";</script>');
```